# Data "modules" for an android game?

Tags: java, android

I currently working on an android game, and ran into a pretty big problem (for me, at least):

When the game will be finished, I wish to add buyable "modules" for it (it will be a photo-based game, and the modules will be picture packs). But the modules tend to be kind of big (around 5-10mb each) and will be themed, so it is very likely that users don't want to download each, so I don't want to merge them into the core game.

The question: are there any way to add a separate modules for a game, which can be downloaded, but then the core game will able to read out the files from package, without adding them to the core?

So far the only solution I found was the "FileProvider", but I didn't was able to make it work (it can be that I am too lame, but not too sure that was the right way for my problem). If that is the best solution, could someone give me a tutorial or something? The one on the developer.android.com site is using intents, and, if possible, I don't want to start another app to load in the pictures (but if there is no other way, then I give up, and do it that way).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

By adding the same `shareduserID` for both (or more) application, then you can create a context for the other app, and access its assett folder.

This line must be added to the *AndroidManifest.xml* file, inside the application tag:

```
android:sharedUserId="com.example"
```

Then, inside the activity, create a new context this way:

```
Context friendContext = this.createPackageContext("com.otherpackage", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
```

(Where *"com.otherpackage"* is your other application's package.)

Doing this will possible result losing your database, and other associated files, so take care! And to work, both app need to signed by the same keyfile, or you will get an error.